# C++ Lambda expressions: capture by ref overhead

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I noticed that in project I worked on a lot of places where lambda expressions capture pointer on this, but doesn't use it. Does it lead to some kind overhead like pointer copy, or optimized by compiller?

```
void MyClass::SomeFunction()
{
    ...
    grid->ForEachItem([this](const Item& item)
    {
        // Some code doesn't use this
    }
}
```

And the same question dedicated to capture all by reference [&]

Comment: Might be, might not. In any case it lies to the next developer who reads it, so why write it?

Comment: I would bet that compiler will optimise away unused variables, but I'm not sure. Either way I'm not a big fan of throwing around "this" and "&" lambda captures, as this asks for trouble and lack of encapsulation. In addition if it's not used, why not simply remove it, as it just brings confusion to ones who read the code?

Comment: Of course I will remove it, but it interesting does it cauze some overhead. And in case if it used, if it just a pointer copy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally recommend not capturing `this` if it is not used, but most certainly not because of performance reasons.

I will start with the obligatory note about performance: first and foremost write code for readability. And after you profile and identify a real problem, then you can think about optimizing the specific part of the code that is slow. Of course, I am not talking about algorithm complexity, but about *micro optimizations*.

In the case of lambda captures, the compiler is allowed to not actually capture objects that are not used, even if they are captured by copy `[=]`. And on top of this, the fact that the lambda body is fully visible to the compiler coupled with the *as if* rule basically assure that on a modern compiler with optimizations enabled you don't need to worry performance-wise about what you capture.

However the reason I recommend against capturing something you don't use is for readability and expressivity of the expression. If the lambda uses `this` or any other variable for that matter that is a reference or a pointer you need to make sure the lambda doesn't outlive what it captures. For instance if I see a lambda which captures `this` and is returned outside of the method, I am very nervous and take extra care to make sure the object captured doesn't expire before the lambda can be called. And even if that is not a concern (e.g. the lambda doesn't escape outside of the method), the simple confusion of the reader ("this lambda should not use the state of the object, why then does it capture `this`?") is enough of a compelling argument to avoid it.

When looking at the capture list of a lambda you should tell when it's safe to call it. The lambda *lies* if it captures a ref or a pointer to something it doesn't use. Don't write lying lambdas.

---

**TLDR** no overhead, but don't do it for readability and expressivity reasons.

Comment: Thank you for answer. BTW, for lambdas which called outside I prefer captured a week pointer which available for enable_shared_from_this class objects through weak_from_this() and check it in lambda or other kind of functors functor.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it lead to some kind overhead like pointer copy

As far as the abstract machine is concerned: Yes. There will be a pointer copy, and the captured pointer will increase the size of the lambda object.

But if the compiler expands the function invokation inline, then all of that can be optimised to nothing.

> And the same question dedicated to capture all by reference [&]

The capture-default will not capture anything that isn't used by the lambda, whether you use the value or reference capture.